# How could I upload a XLS file to Cloud and then plot it?

Tags: plotting, bugs, wolfram-cloud

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3 or earlier**

---

I want to upload a file to the Wolfram Cloud and  plot the list:
So I use the following code to check its head at the beginning:

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"file" -> "XLS"},Head[#file]&], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Output is:

> CloudObject[
>   https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/7d8de66e-be8b-496e-a692-124593ee3879
>   ]

But when I upload a XLS file and then submit,it can not continue,it throws a error:

***upload a file of type XLS***

[image]

If I check this file type on my computer:

```
FileFormat["F:\\learning_mma\\testfile.xls"]
```

result is:

> XLS

So my question is how to upload a XLS file to the Clould and then plot it?

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63240/upload-a-file-using-a-wolframcloud-webform/63516#63516) is a related question and still unanswered by WRI. I did ask at the WTC conference last week, sent a mail to a main developer, but never heard back (maybe it went into a Spam folder? Or they are very very busy fixing things. Probably.)

Comment: yes,simular this code:CloudDeploy[
FormFunction[{"image" -> "Image"},
EdgeDetect[#image] &, "JPEG"]] can run.and  CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"lis"->"List"},Length[#lis]&],Permissions->"Public"] also can run.But XLS can't be done.

Comment: @Rolf Mertig I feedback to wolfram and get the answer.This is a known issue with using "UploadedFile" with FormFunction. I have updated the bug report with your case.   Thank you very much for giving us feedback.   Sincerely, Xin Xiao  Wolfram Technical Support

Comment: If anyone knows whether this bug has been fixed, please update the bug header (see http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

Comment: @MichaelE2 It works now. Difficult to say which (cloud) version corrected the bug. Not really relevant though, since only the latest version (10.3 at the moment) is accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you create

```
Export["test.xls", RandomReal[1, 42]]
```

Then this seems to work in creating a nice plot (it will not look nice without specifying FontFamily, somehow, strangely).

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[{"file" -> "XLS"}, 
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[First[#file]], 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Tahoma", FontSize -> 16}] &], 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Comment: I tried the following but does not work: `SetDirectory[
  "D:\\World_Bank_projects\Manual_for_Math_Package\Methods_codes_and_\
articles"]; 
Export["deneme.xls", "xls"];
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"deneme" -> "XLS"}]];
Composition[ImportString[#, "XLS"] &, ExportString[#, "Binary"] &, 
  CloudGet]@"deneme.xls"`. The following errors observed: `CloudObject::cloudnf: No CloudObject found at the given address

BinaryWrite::nocoerce: $Failed cannot be coerced to the specified format.

ImportString::string: First argument $Failed is not a string.`

Comment: `Export["deneme.xls", "xls"]` makes no sense. Please read the documentation for Export of Excel fiels.

Comment: I tried this `Export[CloudObject["deneme"], deneme.xls, "xls"]` but not working. I see the `deneme.xls` file on Cloud but it is empty. It should not be empty.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

So, let's hope this will be fixed in the next version.
Until then this simple workaround, using "Binary" as an intermediate format, will do it:

```
  CloudDeploy@
         FormFunction[{"data" -> "Binary"}, 
                     (
                      CloudPut[#data, "excelFile"]; 
                      "Uploaded XLSX"
                     ) &
         ]
```

Then, after uploading an Excel file through the browser,
you can get the content of the Excel file into Mathematica simply by:

```
Composition[ ImportString[#, "XLSX"] &,
             ExportString[#, "Binary"] &,
             CloudGet
] @ "excelFile"
```

Comment: I tried your code above with "XLS" file but it does not work. It cannot find my Excel file in the Cloud. Is this issue solve by now?

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to use a text file instead of XLS, here's the code I use to upload & plot two columns from a text file:

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[
"x" -> "Text",
ListPlot[ImportString[#x, "Data"]] &, "PNG"
], Permissions -> "Public"]
```